# Flask_socketio function join_room not working

Tags: reactjs, flask-socketio

I am trying to build an online game lobby with Flask as my backend and React as my frontend. I am stuck on Flask_socketio's join_room.
After calling join_room, I print out the number of sockets in that room but it always returns me as zero.

This is how I am connecting on my frontend `app.js`:

```
class SocketService {
    socket;

    connect(url) {
        return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
          this.socket = io(url);
    
          if (!this.socket) return rj();
    
          this.socket.on("connect", () => {
            rs(this.socket);
          });
    
          this.socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
            console.log("Connection error: ", err);
            rj(err);
          });
        });
    }
}

const connectSocket = async () => {
    await socketService
      .connect("http://localhost:5001")
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    connectSocket();
  }, []);
```

This is on the server side on my `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, json
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, rooms, join_room, send

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='client/build')
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
api = Api(app)

SOCKETIO = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", json=json, manage_session=True, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@SOCKETIO.on('join_game')
def joinGame(message):
    connectedSockets = rooms(message['roomId'])
    print('Received join game request to room:', message['roomId'])
    print('Number of sockets in this room:', len(connectedSockets))

    if len(connectedSockets) >= 2:
        SOCKETIO.emit("room_join_error", {
            'error': "Room is full! Please choose another room to play."
        })
    else:
        roomId = message['roomId']
        join_room(roomId)
        print("A user joined this room: ", roomId)
        print("Number of users in room after joining: ", len(rooms(roomId)))
        send("A new user has joined this room.", to=roomId)
        SOCKETIO.emit("room_joined")

    if (len(connectedSockets) == 2):
        SOCKETIO.emit("start_game", {
            'start': True,
            'symbol': "X"
        })
        SOCKETIO.to(message['roomId']).emit("start_game", {
            'start': False,
            'symbol': "O"
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SOCKETIO.run(
        app=app,
        # host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),
        port=5001,
        debug=True
    )
```

This is the terminal [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2K9K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rooms()` function returns a list of the rooms the client is in. You seem to be using it to get the list of users in a room, which is incorrect.

The Flask-SocketIO package does not provide a function that returns the list of users in a room, but you can create a data structure that keeps track of users in each room in your own application.